# Append the row to DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I appended the row which is coming as a dynamic json response to a datatable which is already initialized but it is not taking the api properties (pagination,sorting,searching). I tried with  `$('#example').row.add(itemsHtml).draw();` method also but no result, even 
I tried the `fn` functions of datatable but no result. If any one knows the solution for this help here. Find the code below.

Comment: There is no "code below"...

Comment: Add your code to question.